# Making my website scale able to mobile devices

Tags: html, css

Trying to scale my website to mobile devices, I'm not allowed to use any sorts of frameworks.

I think previewing it in blocks underneath each other on mobile devices? How would I go about doing that, because my text will mix with my image and nav bar links will get messed up and slide on top of each other?

I read something with responsive navbar making it into a hamburger menu when screen becomes smaller.

Viewport is set at:
`<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">`

```css
* {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}
body, html {
    height: 100%;
    font-family: Camingo, sans-serif;
}

.bg {
    /* The image used */
    background-image: url("https://jackdijkema.000webhostapp.com/pics/skrrrt.jpg");
    /* Full height */
    height: 100%;
    /* Center and scale the image nicely */
    background-position: center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    position: relative;
}
.AboutMe {
    /* The image used */
    background-color: white;
    /* Full height */
    height: 50%;
    /* Center and scale the image nicely */
    background-position: center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    position: relative;
}
.Hoofdnav {
    font-family: Camingo, sans-serif;
    font-size: 25px;
    width: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 100px;
    font-weight: 300;
}

.Hoofdnav li {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 33.3%;
    text-align: center;
}

.Hoofdnav ul {
    letter-spacing: 4px;
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 30%;
}

.Hoofdnav a {
    color: white;
    text-decoration: none;
}
.Hoofdnav a:hover {
    font-weight: bold;
    text-outline: white 2px;
}
.AboutMe h1  {
    font-family: Camingo;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 20px;
    font-weight: 700;
    margin-top: 3% ;
    text-transform: uppercase;
/*    text-decoration: underline;*/
    position:absolute;
    margin-left: 25%;
}
.AboutMe p {
    font-family: Camingo, sa;
    text-align: left;
    margin-top: -18% ;
    margin-left: 25%;
    font-size: 19px;s

}
.AboutMe img {
    margin-top: 1.5%;
    margin-left: 5%;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="nl">

<head>
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
 <title>Jack Dijkema</title>
 <link href="CSS/main.css" rel="stylesheet" />
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="CSS/header.css" />
 <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Permanent+Marker:400' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
 <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="180x180" href="/pics/apple-touch-icon.png">
 <link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="32x32" href="/pics/favicon-32x32.png">
 <link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="16x16" href="/pics/favicon-16x16.png">
 <link rel="manifest" href="/pics/site.webmanifest">
 <link rel="mask-icon" href="/pics/safari-pinned-tab.svg" color="#5bbad5">
 <link rel="shortcut icon" href="/pics/favicon.ico">
 <meta name="msapplication-TileColor" content="#da532c">
 <meta name="msapplication-config" content="/pics/browserconfig.xml">
 <meta name="theme-color" content="#ffffff">
</head>
<body>
 <div class="bg"></div>
<hr>
 <div class="AboutMe">
  <h1>ABOUT</h1>
      <img src="https://jackdijkema.000webhostapp.com/pics/rsz_150982648_370567113534046_8331947271073836645_n%20(1).jpg" alt="Picture of Jack Dijkema About me section">
    <p>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Pellentesque sit amet hendrerit turpis.<br> Mauris commodo
    est ex, ac convallis tellus feugiat ac.<br>
    Praesent sit amet arcu quis elit pulvinar rhoncus.<br> Proin viverra lacinia ante, at interdum magna posuere eget.
    Cras rhoncus a neque ac scelerisque.<br> Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus.
    </p>
   </div>
<div class="myProjects">
 <footer>
 Jack Dijkema Copyright 2019 - 
</footer>
</div>
<nav class="Hoofdnav">
  <ul>
   <li><a href="index.html">AboutMe</a></li><li><a href="index.html">Projects</a></li><li><a  rel="noopener" target="_blank" href="pdf/Jack%20Dijkema%20CV.pdf">CV</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
</body>
</html>
```

```
I also uploaded the whole website to:
https://jackdijkema.000webhostapp.com/

If u scale it to mobile device everything gets messed up.
```

Comment: to achieve what you need , you just use javascript or just adjust you css setting to suite any media as you need

Comment: It seems like we are missing code that would help us solve the issue, but I do like the direction you are going with your website.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend reading through this [wiki on W3Schools.](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_responsive.asp)

Essentially what you need to do is look into media queries in CSS, as that allows you to set different styling for when the screen is at a certain size.

You can also check out this [example of a responsive header.](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_responsive_header.asp) A responsive design without using Bootstrap or a framework is possible using media queries.